# gcc force not to use DSP

Tags: c, gcc, signal-processing, compiler-flags

Is it possible to force a tricore-gcc (which has mostly the same flags as gcc) compiler to not use special instructions?

I want to measure the run time of code on a microcontroller which has DSP capabilities.

```
uint32_t c[100],b[100],a[100];
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    c[i] += a[i]*b[i];
}
```

for example is translated to a special MAC instruction which uses the DSP and will return the result faster than the ALU would calculate it.

I now want to test how much faster it is, not by manually counting cycles given in the manual (because of stalls etc..). Is it somehow possible to tell the compiler not to use the DSP, or more specifically not to use one special assembly instruction?

Thanks

Comment: You could try using `-march=name[+option...]` with the `‘+nodsp’` option. An example would be `-march=armv8-m.main+nodsp`.

Comment: If you know what instructions you want it to emit, could you just write the mac in assembler?

Comment: @colin yes, I had that idea too, but I still hope it can be done using some compiler flags

Comment: The gcc manual is quite fine. What did you try and why did it not work?

Comment: @toohonestforthissite i have got a manual from the tricore-gcc compiler and did not find anything about such a feature.